# New to Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, matrix

I would like to build a program to manipulate multidimensional arrays, a new concept for me i would like to learn....

I assume it could have a few methods...

```
public int get(int row, int column)
//  a method to get the value in row/column
//  keep in mind columns/rows start at 0


public void set(int row, int column, int value)
// a method to set the matrix element to the value
// again keep in mind columns/rows start at 0


public void negate()
// method that negates through each element

public void add(Matrix m)
// adds the matrix m to this
```

can anyone tell me if this is a correct approach and how can i go about doing this?
thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds good. Are you asking about what kinds of data structures to use, or how you would go about implementing these methods?

Comment: looks good and your code have a comment that describe each method

Comment: @chm052 implementing them! :D

Comment: method naming negate. what it means? Method name should define the functionality of the method

Comment: try writing a program yourself. if you get stuck ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this implementation and analyze it, if this is for homework then 'clipboard inheritance' won't do you good if you don't know whats going on.

```
    public class Matrix
{
    private double[][] matrixData;

    private int col;

    private int row;

    /**
     * Create matrix of zero size
     */
    public Matrix()
    {
        this(0);
    }

    public Matrix(double[][] matrixData)
    {
        this.matrixData = matrixData;

        this.row = matrixData.length;
        this.col = matrixData[0].length;
    }

    public Matrix(double[] matrixData)
    {
        this.row = matrixData.length;
        for (int i = 0, size = matrixData.length; i < size; i++)
        {
            this.matrixData[0][i] = matrixData[i];
        }
    }

    public Matrix(int size)
    {
        this.matrixData = new double[size][size];
        this.col = size;
        this.row = size;
    }

    public Matrix(int row, int col)
    {
        matrixData = new double[row][col];
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }

    /**
     * Static method which creates a matrix with a single column.
     * 
     * @param input
     * @return
     */
    public static Matrix createColumnMatrix(final double input[])
    {
        double result[][] = new double[input.length][1];
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
            result[i][0] = input[i];

        return new Matrix(result);
    }

    /**
     * Static method which creates a matrix with a single row.
     * 
     * @param input
     * @return
     */
    public static Matrix createRowMatrix(final double input[])
    {
        double result[][] = new double[1][input.length];
        for (int i = 0, size = input.length; i < size; i++)
            result[0][i] = input[i];

        return new Matrix(result);
    }

    /**
     * Convert the matrix into a one dimentional matrix
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public double[] toPackedArray()
    {
        int size = row * col;
        int index = 0;
        double[] results = new double[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                results[index++] = matrixData[i][j];

        return results;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified value to given cell in the matrix.
     * 
     * @param row
     * @param col
     * @param value
     */
    public void add(final int row, final int col, final double value)
    {
        matrixData[row][col] += value;
    }

    /**
     * Sets every cell in a matrix to zero.
     */
    public void clear()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                matrixData[i][j] = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        return new Matrix(matrixData);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Matrix))
        {
            return false;
        }
        Matrix that = (Matrix)obj;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                if (matrixData[i][j] != that.get(i,j))
                    return false;
            }

        return true;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrixData.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrixData[i].length; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(matrixData[i][j] + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets one column of a matrix object as a new matrix object.
     * 
     * @param col
     * @return
     */
    public Matrix getCol(final int col)
    {
        double[] results = new double[matrixData[col].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            results[i] = matrixData[i][col];

        return Matrix.createColumnMatrix(results);
    }

    /**
     * Gets one row of a matrix object as a new matrix object.
     * 
     * @param row
     * @return
     */
    public Matrix getRow(final int row)
    {
        double[] results = new double[this.row];
        for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
            results[i] = matrixData[row][i];

        return Matrix.createRowMatrix(results);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the sum of every cell in a matrix object.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public double sum()
    {
        double total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                total += matrixData[i][j];
            }
        return total;
    }

    /**
     * Determines if every cell in a matrix object is zero.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isZero()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                if (matrixData[i][j] != 0)
                    return false;
            }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get given value at a specific location
     * 
     * @param row
     * @param col
     * @return
     */
    public double get(int row, int col)
    {
        return matrixData[row][col];
    }

    public int getCols()
    {
        return col;
    }

    public int getRows()
    {
        return row;
    }

    public static Matrix identity(final int size)
    {
        final Matrix result = new Matrix(size,size);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            result.set(i,i,1);
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Set given row and column using 0 based indexes
     * 
     * @param row
     * @param col
     * @param value
     */
    public void set(int row, int col, double value)
    {
        matrixData[row][col] = value;
    }

    /**
     * Get the copy of the current matrix
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public double[][] getRawMatrix()
    {
        double[][] copy = new double[matrixData.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < matrixData.length; i++)
        {
            copy[i] = new double[matrixData[i].length];
            for (int j = 0; j < matrixData[i].length; j++)
                copy[i][j] = matrixData[i][j];
        }
        return copy;
    }

    public static void dump(double[] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
        }
    }

    public void dump()
    {
        dump(System.out);
    }

    public void dump(PrintStream ps)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                ps.print(matrixData[i][j] + ", ");
            }
            ps.println();
        }
        ps.println();
    }

    public void add(Matrix contribution)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Comment: to test my code, similar layout to this, would I just specify row and column length in my constructor?

Comment: You can ether do 'new Matrix(4) or new Matrix(2,4)' or clone a existing matrix,

Answer (score 2):

Your approach looks generally sensible.

A few things to think about:

- `int` isn't really a good choice for a fundamental data type for mathematical matrices. For example, you can't usually get an accurate inverse of an `int` matrix. Are you sure you wouldn't rather use `double` instead?
- It can be a good idea to make such vectors / matrices *immutable*. In which case `add`, `set` and `negate` should return a new matrix. The only real argument in favour of mutability is performance (but in that case... you should be using an existing library rather than rolling your own!)

If you want to use or study an existing library that does stuff like this (and a lot more besides) then you might be interested in my rather extensive vector/matrix maths library:

- https://github.com/mikera/vectorz

Vectorz is focused specifically on primitive `double` arrays for fast numerical work, but the same principles would apply for arrays / matrices of any type.

Answer (score 1):

> can anyone tell me if this is a correct approach and how can i go about doing this?

Yes, absolutely.

However, as a convention comments should be above the method declaration. and called method header.

for example:

```
//  a method to get the value in row/column
//  keep in mind columns/rows start at 0
public int get(int row, int column)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interface (i.e. your planned methods) seems very reasonable.

As for general multidimensional array manipulation, there are lots of tutorials available on this, e.g. [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/multi-dimensional_arrays.html), [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ctab5xPv-Vk), [here](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/46191-multidimensional-arrays/), and [here](http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-arrays.html).

Aaand to get you started, simple code examples:

**Creating awesome multidimensional arrays**

```
int[][] multi = new int[2][3]; // this mda has two rows and three columns
```

**Accessing their rad elements**

```
int el = multi[0][1]; // el is in the first row, second column
```

**Iterating through them like a boss**

```
for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < multi.length; rowNum++) {
    for (int colNum = 0; colNum < multi[rowNum].length; colNum++) {
        int currentElement = multi[rowNum][colNum];
    }
}
```